# Django easy_thumbnails accessing image URLs

Tags: django, json, thumbnails, easy-thumbnails

Is it possible to access the URLs of easy_thumbs created images?

I have a model with an `ImageField` and a `ModelForm` to match.

```
# models.py

class ModelWithAnImage(models.Model):
    image = ThumbnailerImageField(
        upload_to='images',
    )
```

Following the [documentation](http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#pregeneration) I am using signals to generate two thumbs when the image is uploaded.

```
# somewherethatdefinitelygetsloaded.py

from easy_thumbnails.signals import saved_file
from easy_thumbnails.signal_handlers import generate_aliases_global


saved_file.connect(generate_aliases_global)
```

This is working fine but is it possible to then access the url for those thumbs?

.

`model_with_an_image.image.url` returns the original image (as you'd expect).

The aim is to send the thumb url via AJAX to an external source so the `{% thumbnail %}` is not going to help me at the moment.

```
# requirements.txt

Django==1.5.1
Pillow==2.0.0
boto==2.9.0
django-storages==1.1.8
easy-thumbnails==1.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation points to the [`thumbnail_url`](http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#thumbnail-url-filter) template filter, which can return the URL of a thumnail inside a template.

You can call the template filter like a real function from your view (or anywhere else), and it should work just as fine as in a template, e.g.:

```
from easy_thumbnails.templatetags.thumbnail import thumbnail_url

thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url(model_with_an_image, 'small')
```

Behind the scenes, the filter just calls [`get_thumbnailer`](http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#get-thumbnailer) so you could also write:

```
thumbnailer = get_thumbnailer(model_with_an_image)
thumbnailer.generate = False  # so a not generate a thumb if sthg went wrong
thumbnail = thumbnailer.get_thumbnail(thumbnail_options)
#  do stuff with thumbnail.url
```

Comment: Ah of course! Missed that and I had even linked to the documentation, n00b mistake :-)  Thanks.