# Django Rest Framework with easy-thumbnails

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, easy-thumbnails

With a normal ImageField, serializing the URL is simply `image = serializers.ImageField()`. What should it look like when using easy-thumbnails?

So far, I've only found a function for getting the URL: [Django easy_thumbnails accessing image URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174675/django-easy-thumbnails-accessing-image-urls)
Using this in a serializer would require a SerializerMethodField, which is an unsatisfying solution. I'm looking for a solution that's as efficient/performant as practical, and on one line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best solution is probably to subclass `serializers.ImageField()` and use the the code you found in the `to_representation` method ([docs for custom fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields)). Your field could then look like this:

```
from easy_thumbnails.templatetags.thumbnail import thumbnail_url

class ThumbnailSerializer(serializers.ImageField):

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return thumbnail_url(instance, 'small')
```

Answer (score 3):

settings.py

```
THUMBNAIL_ALIASES = {
    '': {
        'small': {'size': (40, 40)},
        'medium': {'size': (128, 128)},
    },
}
```

api/serializers.py

```
from easy_thumbnails.templatetags.thumbnail import thumbnail_url


class ThumbnailSerializer(serializers.ImageField):
    def __init__(self, alias, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.read_only = True
        self.alias = alias

    def to_representation(self, value):
        if not value:
            return None

        url = thumbnail_url(value, self.alias)
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        if request is not None:
            return request.build_absolute_uri(url)
        return url
```

using

```
from api.serializers import ThumbnailSerializer


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = ThumbnailSerializer(alias='medium')
    avatar = ThumbnailSerializer(alias='small', source='image')
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is.
Step 1. Install sorl-thumbnail and add it to settings.py

```
pip install sorl-thumbnail 
./manage.py migrate
```

Step 2. Install sorl-thumbnail-serializer-field

```
pip install sorl-thumbnail-serializer-field
```

Add it to settings.py. Sample usage as stated in documentation (https://github.com/dessibelle/sorl-thumbnail-serializer-field)

```
class TestModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel

    # A thumbnail image, sorl options and read-only
    thumbnail = HyperlinkedSorlImageField(
        '128x128',
        options={"crop": "center"},
        source='image',
        read_only=True
    )

    # A larger version of the image, allows writing
    image = HyperlinkedSorlImageField('1024')
```

Django 3.0 compatibility has not been updated yet for sorl-thumbnail. So in case of django 3.0 at the present time.

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/jazzband/sorl-thumbnail@4fe1854#egg=sorl-thumbnail
```

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? Link can expire in any moment, so it is better to have whole description of your solution here. Thank you!

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192), or if possible all of the above.

Answer (score 1):

A simple package to serialize easy thumbnailer field: https://github.com/yashas123/easy-thumbnails-rest